# Accessing object through name stored in variable

Tags: javascript, object

I've seen variations of this question before but most assume you know the name of the object and reference object properties only. In my situation it's the opposite - I know each of the object's properties but I don't know it's name. However, the name is stored in one of the properties of a known object.

In the example I have below, I know that the object "north" of `room1` is named `room2`. Is there a way for me to access `room2` properties by referencing `room1.north`? Something to the effect `[room1.north].description`?

```
    var room1 = {
        north: "room2",
        east: "room3",
        south: "nothing",
        west: "room4"
    }

    var room2 = {
        description: "description of the room"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for instance `window[room1.north].description`. Depending of course of the scope.